# Hexo automatically adds data-checked-head="true" attribute in the script tag when I add google autoad script for website verification

Tags: adsense, hexo

I am adding Google Adsense Auto Ads verification script in the head tag of my Hexo blog which has clean-blog theme installed.
The original script is

```
<script data-ad-client="ca-pub-8344324360472051" async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
```

But upon deployment it adds a new attribute `data-checked-head="true"` in the script tag, and makes the script as shown below

```
<script data-ad-client="ca-pub-8344324360472051" async="" src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js" data-checked-head="true"></script>
```

Because of this change which Hexo does automatically, Google fails to verify my website. Please help!

Comment: Did you find a solution?